# How to use expression-templates for specific types?

Tags: c++, templates, expression-templates

When using expression templates, how do I create specializations? From the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates), I can make a Vector sum template class like so:

```
template <typename E1, typename E2>
class VecSum : public VecExpression<VecSum<E1, E2> > {
    E1 const& _u;
    E2 const& _v;
public:
    VecSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : _u(u), _v(v) {
        assert(u.size() == v.size());
    }
    double operator[](size_t i) const { return _u[i] + _v[i]; }
    size_t size()               const { return _v.size(); }
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
VecSum<E1,E2> const
operator+(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) {
   return VecSum<E1, E2>(u, v);
}
```

According to Wikipedia, if I have a `Vector` class that extends `VecExpression<Vector>` and a constructor from the `VecExpression` class that uses the `[]` operator and a loop, this will allow loop merging so statements like the following only use a single loop:

```
Vector a = ...;
Vector b = ...;
Vector c = ...;
Vector d = a+b+c;
```

I get why this works, but I'm not sure how to extend it to scalars. I want to be able to add a scalar (int, float, or double) to the entire Vector, but I'm not sure how to do this. My best guess is to create specializations for the VecSum class like:

```
template<typename E2> VecSum<int, E2>{ /*stuff goes here*/ }
template<typename E1> VecSum<E1, int>{ /*stuff goes here*/ }
template<typename E2> VecSum<float, E2>{ /*stuff goes here*/ }
template<typename E1> VecSum<E1, float>{ /*stuff goes here*/ }
template<typename E2> VecSum<double, E2>{ /*stuff goes here*/ }
template<typename E1> VecSum<E1, double>{ /*stuff goes here*/ }
```

But this seems like its a lot more work than is necessary, is there another solution?

Comment: What is `int + E2` supposed to mean? What do you think its `operator[]` should be?

Comment: @PasserBy I wasn't very clear about that. In each of the VecSum specializations, in the `operator[]` code, I would simply do something like `_u+_v[i]`, only using `[]` on the non-scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use SFINAE to check if the type is an arithmethic one and specialize as needed.

Example:

```
template <typename E1, typename E2, typename Enable = void > class VecSum;

template <typename E1, typename E2>
class VecSum< E1, E2,
      typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic<E1>::value && !std::is_arithmetic<E2>::value>
      > : public VecExpression<VecSum<E1, E2> >
{
    E1 const& _u;
    E2 const& _v;

    public:

    VecSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : _u(u), _v(v)
    {
        assert(u.size() == v.size());
    }

    double operator[](size_t i) const { return _u[i] + _v[i]; }
    size_t size()               const { return _v.size(); }
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
class VecSum < E1, E2,
      typename std::enable_if_t< std::is_arithmetic<E1>::value && !std::is_arithmetic<E2>::value>
      > : public VecExpression<VecSum<E1, E2> >
{
    E1 const& _u;
    E2 const& _v;

    public:

    VecSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : _u(u), _v(v)
    {
    }

    double operator[](size_t i) const { return _u + _v[i]; }
    size_t size()               const { return _v.size(); }
};


template <typename E1, typename E2>
class VecSum < E1, E2,
      typename std::enable_if_t< !std::is_arithmetic<E1>::value && std::is_arithmetic<E2>::value>
      > : public VecExpression<VecSum<E1, E2> >
{
    E1 const& _u;
    E2 const& _v;

    public:

    VecSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : _u(u), _v(v)
    {
    }

    double operator[](size_t i) const { return _u[i] + _v; }
    size_t size()               const { return _u.size(); }
};

int main(){
    Vec v0 = { 1, 2, 3 ,4 };
    Vec v1 = {10, 20,30,40 };
    Vec v2 = {100,200,300,400 };

    {

        Vec sum = v0+v1+v2;
        Vec v3(4);

        for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
            v3[i]=sum[i];


        for(unsigned int i=0;i<v3.size();++i)
            std::cout << v3[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "with lhs skalar" << std::endl;

    {
        Vec sum = 5 + 50 + v1;
        Vec v3(4);

        for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
            v3[i]=sum[i];


        for(unsigned int i=0;i<v3.size();++i)
            std::cout << v3[i] << std::endl;

    }

    std::cout << "with rhs skalar" << std::endl;

    {
        Vec sum = v1 + 5 + 50 ;
        Vec v3(4);

        for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
            v3[i]=sum[i];


        for(unsigned int i=0;i<v3.size();++i)
            std::cout << v3[i] << std::endl;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about an alternative:

```
class AnySize { };
bool operator==(AnySize, AnySize) { return true; }
bool operator==(size_t, AnySize) { return true; }
bool operator==(AnySize, size_t) { return true; }

template <typename T>
class Scalar {
    T _value;

public:
    explicit Scalar(T value) : _value(value) {}
    T operator[](int) { return _value; }
    AnySize size() { return {}; }
}
```

You will also need to change `VecExpression::size`, to give an appropriate size rather than always the left hand side's

```
AnySize size_for(AnySize, AnySize) { return {}; }
size_t size_for(size_t lhs, AnySize) { return lhs; }
size_t size_for(AnySize, size_t rhs) { return rhs; }
size_t size_for(size_t lhs, size_t rhs) { return lhs; }

auto VecExpression<E1,E2>::size() { return size_for(_u.size(), _v.size()); }
```

Comment: While this does work, it may be better to add a size function to the Scalar class that returned a flag value (like -1), so I could add an if statement to check for it in VecSum's constructor. This way I could still keep the error checking if someone tried to add vectors of different sizes.

Comment: @BadProgrammer99 I prefer a marker type rather than a marker value. also remember that `std::size_t` is unsigned, so -1 becomes some large value.